# How to cancel a text that hasn't sent, before it does send?

Tags: iphone

I accidentally sent a text while my iPhone was in Airplane mode. I realised upon further consideration, that I would rather not send it.

Is there any way to cancel the text before taking the phone out of Airplane mode and make sure it doesn't get delivered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Failed delivery of a message while in Airplane mode is represented by a **Not Delivered** subtext below the message text. To safely delete it without sending, simply tap and hold on the message, tap **More...**, select the message by tapping on the checkbox shown towards left and tap on **Delete Message** button.

[image] [image] [image]

Alternatively, delete the entire message thread by navigating back to list of messages, swiping left on conversation thread to reveal the **Delete** button and tapping **Delete** button shown at the bottom.

[image] [image]

Comment: Won't your message maybe have already been delivered before you can navigate back and delete message thread?

Comment: As stated in the question, the answer assumes that the user is in Airplane mode while performing the actions.

Comment: The only problem would be if you’re connected to WIFi while in airplane mode. This is a solid answer nonetheless.